# Algorithm Analysis: In practice, do coefficients of higher order terms matter?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

Consider `an^2 + bn + c`. I understand that for large `n`, `bn` and `c` become insignificant.

I also understand that for large `n`, the differences between `2n^2` and `n^2` are pretty insignificant *compared to* the differences between, say `n^2` and `n*log(n)`.

However, there is still an order of 2 difference between `2n^2` and `n^2`. Does this matter in practice? Or do people just think about algorithms without coefficients? Why?

Comment: [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) is probably a better site for this kind of question.

Comment: When N is large enough, constant coefficients don't matter for complexity analysis.

Comment: @irrelephant I [posted](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/264190/algorithm-analysis-in-practice-do-coefficients-of-higher-order-terms-matter) in Programmers.SE. Thanks for the tip

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has been cross-posted.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Yeah, I tried to delete this but it said I can't because there are answers.

Answer (score 2):

The actual coefficients matter if you're interested in timing. But big-O isn't actually about timing, it's about scalability.  When you see an algorithm described as O(n^2), you don't really know how long it will take to solve a problem of size n on a particular computer in a particular language with a particular compiler, but you know that a problem of size 2n should take about 4 times as long.

The reason you can ignore the coefficients is that if you consider the ratio of different size problems, the lower order terms' coefficients are asymptotically dominated, and the highest order term's coefficients cancel in the ratio.

Answer (score 0):

We use time complexity analysis to help us estimate the time cost and understand how far we can go. For example, the lower bound time complexity for sorting algorithm is O(nlgn), it is proved in theory, and we should never try to design a algorithm better than this.

For the coefficient, in many case it's not easy to find a accurate number in theory, since it could be effect by the input data. But it doesn't mean it's not important. Quicksort is the most widely used sorting algorithm, since the coefficient of time complexity is really small, which is only 1.39NlgN for average case.

And another interesting fact about quicksort is that we all know that the worst case for quicksort will cost O(N^2). We can use [Median of Medians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) algorithm to reduce the worst case time complexity of quicksort to O(NlgN), but we seldom use this version in practice. It's because that the coefficient of [Median of Medians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) version is too big, which make it unusable.